# File gssapi.js/package.json not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose

After installing mongodb and mongoose I have error in

```
var mongodb = require('mongoose');
```

ENOTDIR .....node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/gssapi.js/package.json
VS Code, OS Ubuntu, libkrb5-dev installed.

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try This `sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev`

Comment: libkrb5-dev is installed and it doesn't fix this problem.

Comment: code: "ENOTDIR", errno: -20, message: "ENOTDIR: not a directory, stat '/home/andrew/Desktop/Timetable/node_modules/mong... (length: 142)", path: "/home/andrew/Desktop/Timetable/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/gssapi.js/package.json", stack: undefined, syscall: "stat"

Comment: Follow this link (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/getting-started/installation-guide/)

Comment: No changes after this steps.

Comment: if i start project from console using node src/app.js i haven't any errors